# Email validation MX Lookup

Tags: email, email-validation

I have been asked to implement some email address validation on a web app - I'm sure we've all been there a thousand times... however, this time I have been asked to do an MX Lookup on the domain to see if it accepts emails.

Does anyone know of any potential problems with doing this? Is an mx lookup a reliable way of finding out if a domain accepts email? are there any edge cases where a valid email address could fail an MX lookup check?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> are there any edge cases where a valid email address could fail an MX lookup check?

Yes, in that where there is no MX record, MTAs fall back to using the A record instead. So only allowing MX records would fail a class of mail servers that work in the real world.

Allowing any name with an MX *or* A record at least detects obvious mistypings that result in NXDOMAIN. However it will still allow mistypings that end up at squatter sites. A further step for addresses resolved by A records might be to check where port 25 is accepting connections on that address.

Comment: For A records, wouldn't other ports such as 2525/587/465/2526 work too? Cheers~

Comment: @lulalala: for accepting incoming public e-mail, that port must always be 25. Port 587 and custom alternatives are for outgoing mail submission.

Comment: These days (2018), is it "MX or A or AAAA"? I'm guessing most MTAs don't support IPv6 still, but to be sure, we should include an AAAA check right?

Answer (score 2):

You can only check if there is an mail server registered for the domain.

If the server also accepts mails and if the address is valid (not syntactically but in the sense that there exists a inbox for it and so on...) you will only find out when sending the e.g. registration email

sample on how to do this in PHP

```
function mailserver_exists($email) {
 list($user,$domain) = split('@',$email);
 //included check for 'A' after [comment from bobince][1]
 return checkdnsrr($domain,'MX') || checkdnsrr($domain,'A');
}
if(domain_exists('joe@foreigndomain.xx')) {...} else {...}
```

Yes you can use `'TinyTim@192.184.165.13'` too. The PHP documentation for [`checkdnsrr(host, type)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php) states

> host may either be the IP address in
>   dotted-quad notation or the host name

Comment: Hi Jitter - thanks for the response.

Do you know if MX lookups will work if the email address is using IP Address: something like TinyTim@192.184.165.13

Comment: expanded answer to answer your additional question