# Email Validation using MX

Tags: email, dns, jndi, email-validation, mx-record

Need to implement the email validation to find if the email really exists. After some search found that the this is not possible due to the spam control techniques used (e.g. grey listing).

So moved with MX and A attribute check (as we are not allowed to send confirmation mails directly):

`DirContext ictx = new InitialDirContext();
Attributes attrs = ictx.getAttributes("gmail.com",
                                       new String[] {"MX"});`

I am getting the results but not sure how the dns lookup works here (the complete background of the request and response i.e  how the request is forwarded to the mail exchange server and also which port is used for the contacting the Mail Exchange server)

This will immensely help in moving into the production env without any doubts about the network behavior as we are having strick firewall restrictions.

Production Env : Weblogic Server on Solaris OS.

Similar dicussion is at [Email validation MX Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666807/email-validation-mx-lookup) but it doesnt have enough detail

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're confusing two different techniques:

1) Perform a DNS lookup to ensure that an MX record exists for the domain. This will eliminate all email addresses at fake (i.e., not registered) domains. Note however that having an MX record is not a requirement for legitimate mail reception. In the absence of an MX record, the mail software will simply use the A record for the base domain.

2) Make a TCP connection to the recipient mail server to see if anything is listening. This is always port 25. You don't have to send a test message, you can just connect to the port and then immediately disconnect. A successful connection implies a valid email address. (Or at least, a valid domain, which is as much as you can verify.)

Comment: Alex, I am clear with the point 2 you have mentioned, i have tried it and works for most for the email providers (gmail, hotmail etc) but failed for others... But i want to know how point 1 works i.e. how the DNS lookup works

Comment: Are you asking, what's the theory behind why the test works? Or how to actually perform the test in your chosen language?

Comment: how the test works??? i know that the dns server is contacted to get the results.. but there is a strict firewall restriction in our QA enviornmnet but still i could do a DNS lookup on MX record.. so basically how is the DNS lookup made...

Comment: thanks alex... But as i have stated i have already tested mx validation and also the partial envelope similar to the site you jave suggested... But i am having theoritical doubts of  how the dns lookup takes place...  How come firewall restrict contacting the mx server but not the dns look up on mx???  So i am missing granular parts of dns lookup... Note that both dns lookup and contacting the mx works fine in my home n/w...